# How should I persist validation info from validation page to upload/import page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am developing a spreadsheet uploader tool which creates/updates contacts, which will be added as a new option to my website.

The spreadsheet has the following columns:

- Full Name
- Job Title
- Salutation
- Qualifications
- Company Name
- Address Line 1
- Address Line 2
- Address Line 3

The database table structure is as below:

```
Contact(contact_id INT PK IDENTITY(1,1), fullname VARCHAR(30), jobtitle VARCHAR(100), salutation VARCHAR(100), qualifications VARCHAR(100), companyname VARCHAR(100) , address1 VARCHAR(100), address2 VARCHAR(100), address3 VARCHAR(100))
```

The rules are:

```
1. The Full name must contain at least one space (leading and/or trailing spaces will be trimmed).
2. Total length of the full name must not exceed 30 characters (including any space(s)).
3. 'Full Name' is the key field to identify an existing contact in the system. As such, raise a validation error if this field is
blank.
4. If a match is found on the 'Full Name', then the other fields of the contact will be updated with the values populated in the
spreadsheet.
5. If a match is not found on the key field, then create a new contact with the details.
6. When creating/updating a contact a value must be populated in at least one other column (in addition to the 'Full Name'), otherwise
raise a validation error.
```

The process:

There are two phases called 'Validation Phase' and 'Actual Upload' phase.
- When the spreadsheet is uploaded the spreadsheet has to be validated as per the rules above and display the validation/status messages (on screen):
For example:

```
Row 1 is the header row so it will not be validated.
Row 2: Error - Full Name cannot be empty
Row 3: OK - A contact will be created
Row 4: OK - Contact will be updated
Row 5: Error - Full Name must contain at least one space
Row 6: Error - At least one other column must be populated in addition to the 'Full Name'
```

The user will have two options here:

1. Cancel - Then the upload will not be proceeded any further (so the user will have a choice to correct the rows as per validation messages then re-upload it).
2. Continue - Then the upload will move to 'Actual Upload' phase and the contacts will either be created or updated (if there are no validation errors as per the rules above). 
   Also, the validation/status message (similar to the messages in validation phase) should be displayed on screen after the successful upload.

I have managed to work out everything I had illustrated above, but I had to re-validate each row in 'Actual Upload' phase (i.e. I'm doing the same checks twice).

My question is, is there a way to preserve the results from the validation phase so I don't have to re-validate each record in the second phase?

I'm develioping this using the NativeExcel libraries on `.NET Framework (Version 4.0.30319.34209)` using `VB.NET/ASP.NET` (and No `VISUAL STUDIO`). 
Please note all the code will be written in the code-behind page using `VB.NET` (I have no choice here, sorry).

Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should edit the title of this question as a question. Should the user be able to continue to upload even when errors were found in the file? Is revalidating so expensive that it's worth avoiding? If you're wanting to only store a list of the "OK" rows, you could create a List(Of Int32) and during the validation phase, add the good row numbers to the list and then use that to determine which rows to import. You could similarly write the entire status into a list of strings using the index of the list as the row number and the validation message in the list.

Comment: @clweeks: Thank you for your comment. Yes, the user would be able to continue to upload even when there were error rows found, however, the error rows will not be imported in the next phase. I would want to maintain all the rows with the status message, but when the user clicks on the Upload button it will be a new page/request so the List created in last stage will not exist anymore after the new page request.

Answer (score 0):

Save the validation status messages as a List(Of String) and then make that a session variable so that you can use it as a prompt during the upload phase.

Answer (score -2):

To read the Excel file:
right-click References>COM>Office xx.x Object Application

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exlApp = new     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook exlWb = exlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\user\Excelfile.xls");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet exlWs = exlWb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        int col = Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Columns.Count);
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(usedRange.Rows.Count);
        exlApp.Visible = true;
        string[,] cellValue = new string[row + 1, col + 1];
        for (int j = 1; j <= row - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= col - 1; k++)
            {
                cellValue[j, k] = exlWs.Cells[j, k + 1].ToString();
            }
         }
        exlWb.Close();
        exlWs = null;
        exlWb = null;
        exlApp.Quit();
        exlApp = null;
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. I was able to read the excel file without any issues.